# How to get stderr using Popen + vim

Tags: python, vim

I am trying capture error messages from gvim using `subprocess.Popen()`, but not having much luck.

```
import sys
import subprocess
import time

ppp = subprocess.Popen(
    ["vim", "-g", "--nofork", "--some_option_that_does_not_exist", "blah"],
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)
time.sleep(1)
poll = ppp.poll()
err = ''
if poll != None and poll != 0:
    err  = ppp.communicate()
print '-------------------------------->>POLL\n',
print poll
print '-------------------------------->>PPP\n',
print ppp
print '-------------------------------->>err\n',
print err
print '--------------------------------<<\n\n',

print 'Trying to get:\n'
subprocess.Popen(
    ["vim", "-g", "--nofork", "--some_option_that_does_not_exist", "sasa"]
)
```

Result:

```
$ ./poperr.py 
-------------------------------->>POLL
1
-------------------------------->>PPP
<subprocess.Popen object at 0xb73effec>
-------------------------------->>err
(None, '')
--------------------------------<<

Trying to get:

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct 26 2012 16:45:52)
Unknown option argument: "--some_option_that_does_not_exist"
More info with: "vim -h"
```

---

The point is to start vim in background and on success continue with script, on error log error message and abort script.

Guess there are some quirks using vim. Have tested various with no luck. Any ideas?

```
vim -h:
    -g                      Run using GUI (like "gvim")
    -f  or  --nofork        Foreground: Don't fork when starting GUI
```

---

### Edit:

To emphasize: It is the `(None, '')` part that is the issue. As one can see `stderr` is an empty string: `''`. If there is no error it will be `None` as well (like `stdout`).

The reason for the *sleep* is to give the sub-process a chance to succeed or fail. However, the *real* script keep polling for status on the process to detect if it has ended during its lifetime. As such the *sleep* is not that important, but reduces stress on the host as a lot of other tasks are skipped.

… and it makes for a more re-producible snippet here. I increased the sleep time in sample to one second to perhaps make it more clear.

---

Another example would be this. In this case `errorfile.txt` is always empty.

```
ppp = subprocess.Popen(
    ["vim", "-g", "--nofork", "--some_option_that_does_not_exist", "blah"],
    stderr=open('errorfile.txt', 'a')
)
```

Comment: Why do you use GVIM when you want to interact with it through the terminal?

Comment: @IngoKarkat: Because it is launched as a background script from another application. As in *"Open Gvim with this file using these options etc."* I am planing on implementing a shell version as well, but working on the GUI part for now.

Comment: I'm just wondering what you could possibly need to do in vim that wouldn't be easier to do directly in python!

Comment: @SteveBarnes: Write python.

Comment: So you are trying to use a script written in python (with vim) to write python using vim....

Comment: @SteveBarnes: No, I'm not trying, I'm doing it. It is a chicken, eggs and scramble thing.

Answer (score 0):

`ppp.communicate()` will not be called unless the process terminates in less than 0.01 seconds, which evidently is not happening. Note that `ppp.communicate()` will wait for the process to finish, so I'm not sure why you do `time.sleep()` and `ppp.poll()`. The following consistently works:

```
import subprocess

stdout, stderr = subprocess.Popen(
    ["vim", "-g", "--nofork", "--nonexistent_option", "blah"],
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
).communicate()

print '---stdout---\n%s\n---stderr---\n%s\n---expected---' % (stdout, stderr)

subprocess.Popen(
    ["vim", "-g", "--nofork", "--nonexistent_option", "blah"]
).wait()
```

Comment: Without the `sleep`, the process will always return success ("None") on poll. Poll is used to check status. If it is not running (`poll !== None`) second step is to check return code: `poll !== 0` means error. (Error code returned by process / vim). Reason to use sleep + poll is that I do not want to use `communicate` ***unless*** start failed – because it is blocking. I only want to use communicate on error, to get error message. As I stated in Q: *"The point is to start vim in background and on success continue with script, on error log error message and abort script."*

Comment: In that case, as far as I can tell, you cannot guarantee at any point that the Vim subprocess has already started without error, so the best you can do is increase the sleep time in order to lower the probability of polling the process before it has had a chance to fail.

Comment: Yes, but that is not the issue at hand. I can increase the sleep time to a second or ten, point is that when I use communicate stderr is empty. On success it is `"None"` on failure it is `""`. I'm unable to read the *"[…] Unknown option argument: "--some_option_that_does_not_exist"[…]"* part. Nor do I get it using your snipet.

Comment: Also, I keep doing poll's on the sub process during the lifetime of the script to detect if application has closed. So the *sleep* part is merely a startup thing such that if fail during first 0.N seconds then abort directly. If a later poll results in status `1` then read error. It is simply a way of approximately decide if it failed and then ***not*** continue with loads of other initiation things that needs to be cleaned up. As in *reduce resource consumption on host if passed options are bad.*. The core of the issue, however, is the inability to read the error message/response.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is then, because my code works consistently for me (assuming the process terminates by itself, as in this case) and even yours sometimes works (depending on whether the process fails in time).